# Too fast circling during the localization

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, acceleration, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When with rviz i inform the estimate localization, the robot start by circling very fasly. It is too fast, and may be dangerous. So how can I decrease the speed?
I tried to reduce in the base_local_params_planner the acc_lim_th et the max_rotationnal_vel, but it doesn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187531/too-fast-circling-during-the--localization/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-24**:
What exactly are you doing? The "2D Pose Estimate" button in rviz should not move the robot at all.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-24**:
I'm doing 2D Pose Estimate and 2D Nav Goal in rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just some sanity checks: Set the rotational recovery to false and see if that rotation stops. Also, try to manually move the robot around to check if it localizes in the map properly.

PS - I have also noticed that in if you reduce the max x and theta velocities below a certain limit, the robot tends to rotate. I do not know what causes this behavior.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1